# Removal of background colour

Tags: logo

[image]Hey guys,

I'm just trying to remove all the blue behind the logo I'm creating for our 7's tour group. I've never really used photoshop. As I just want the green image with the yellow outline.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Is this the ONLY copy you have? it's a fairly compressed raster image file and wont be use for much other than a small logo. 
This would originally have been created as a Vector file (Illustrator, Corel Draw etc) in which you would remove the background in a single click and export at a high quality.

Comment: What have you tried? What are you struggling with?

Comment: Hi. Welcome to GDSE. What software do you have access to?  What have you tried? What has failed?

Comment: We have an entire category of questions about this: [tag:background-removal]. One of those must have an answer you can use! :)

Answer (score 1):

Phew, there are so many ways to do that with this easy kind of image. The easiest way for you would be to just simply use the magic wand or the quick selection tool in photoshop and just erase the background.
Here's a beginner's guide in selection. https://helpx.adobe.com/photoshop/how-to/selection-tools-basics.html
Or just google "How to cut out in photoshop". The internet is flooded with tutorials...